# UICollectionView Layout Buggy

Tags: swift, iphone

Hey guys I’d love some help on an issue I am facing with uicollection view. It’s a uicollectionview inside a .xib with custom cells that I’m loading through UINibs. I almost get the result I’m looking for but there’s some awkward spacing. Also as a note I’m using the layout delegate to calculate the size of the text and then setting the cell but it’s still awkward every time I generate it. Thanks guys.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHSdL.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn3Gc.jpg)

Here is the code I am using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // dataArary is the managing array for your UICollectionView.
    let item = self.visibleSuggestion[indexPath.item]
    
    var itemSize = item.size(withAttributes: [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    ])
    
    itemSize.width += 20
    itemSize.height += 15
    
    return itemSize
}
```

Comment: Are all cells in the same section? Also, have you tried setting the `minimumInteritemSpacing` property of your layout or implementing the `collectionView(_:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt:)` method in your `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` implementation?

Comment: yeah, but nothing changed